# How do I add this code to make my table columns sortable on click?

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, vue-router

I am using Vue.js to put together a simple CRUD app. I have a demo (followed a tutorial) working of it but for the life of me I don't understand how to sort the table columns by clicking on them. I have found a code example of how to do it but I do not understand how to integrate it. I would be so grateful for any help on how to do this.

demo so far: https://codepen.io/figaro/pen/XMWOyj

```
<div class="container">
  <header class="page-header">
    <div class="branding">
      <img src="https://vuejs.org/images/logo.png" alt="Logo" title="Home page" class="logo"/>
      <h1>Vue.js 2 CRUD application</h1>
      <p>Ported from: <a href="http://codepen.io/-a/pen/amOYGp">Vue.js CRUD application</a></p>
    </div>
  </header>
  <main id="app">
    <router-view></router-view>
  </main>
</div>

<template id="product-list">
  <div>
    <div class="actions">
      <router-link class="btn btn-default" v-bind:to="{path: '/add-product'}">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>
        Add product
      </router-link>
    </div>
    <div class="filters row">
      <div class="form-group col-sm-3">
        <label for="search-element">Product name</label>
        <input v-model="searchKey" class="form-control" id="search-element" requred/>
      </div>
    </div>
    <table class="table">
      <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Description</th>
        <th>Price</th>
        <th class="col-sm-2">Actions</th>
      </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
      <tr v-for="product in filteredProducts">
        <td>
          <router-link v-bind:to="{name: 'product', params: {product_id: product.id}}">{{ product.name }}</router-link>
        </td>
        <td>{{ product.description }}</td>
        <td>
          {{ product.price }}
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-euro" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        </td>
        <td>
          <router-link class="btn btn-warning btn-xs" v-bind:to="{name: 'product-edit', params: {product_id: product.id}}">Edit</router-link>
          <router-link class="btn btn-danger btn-xs" v-bind:to="{name: 'product-delete', params: {product_id: product.id}}">Delete</router-link>
        </td>
      </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</template>

<template id="add-product">
  <div>
    <h2>Add new product</h2>
    <form v-on:submit="createProduct">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="add-name">Name</label>
        <input class="form-control" id="add-name" v-model="product.name" required/>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="add-description">Description</label>
        <textarea class="form-control" id="add-description" rows="10" v-model="product.description"></textarea>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="add-price">Price, <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-euro"></span></label>
        <input type="number" class="form-control" id="add-price" v-model="product.price"/>
      </div>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Create</button>
      <router-link class="btn btn-default" v-bind:to="'/'">Cancel</router-link>
    </form>
  </div>
</template>

<template id="product">
  <div>
    <h2>{{ product.name }}</h2>
    <b>Description: </b>
    <div>{{ product.description }}</div>
    <b>Price:</b>
    <div>{{ product.price }}<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-euro"></span></div>
    <br/>
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <router-link v-bind:to="'/'">Back to product list</router-link>
  </div>
</template>

<template id="product-edit">
  <div>
    <h2>Edit product</h2>
    <form v-on:submit="updateProduct">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="edit-name">Name</label>
        <input class="form-control" id="edit-name" v-model="product.name" required/>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="edit-description">Description</label>
        <textarea class="form-control" id="edit-description" rows="3" v-model="product.description"></textarea>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="edit-price">Price, <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-euro"></span></label>
        <input type="number" class="form-control" id="edit-price" v-model="product.price"/>
      </div>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
      <router-link class="btn btn-default" v-bind:to="'/'">Cancel</router-link>
    </form>
  </div>
</template>

<template id="product-delete">
  <div>
    <h2>Delete product {{ product.name }}</h2>
    <form v-on:submit="deleteProduct">
      <p>The action cannot be undone.</p>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button>
      <router-link class="btn btn-default" v-bind:to="'/'">Cancel</router-link>
    </form>
  </div>
</template>
<script>

var products = [
  {id: 1, name: 'Angular', description: 'Superheroic JavaScript MVW Framework.', price: 100},
  {id: 2, name: 'Ember', description: 'A framework for creating ambitious web applications.', price: 100},
  {id: 3, name: 'React', description: 'A JavaScript Library for building user interfaces.', price: 100},
];

function findProduct (productId) {
  return products[findProductKey(productId)];
};

function findProductKey (productId) {
  for (var key = 0; key < products.length; key++) {
    if (products[key].id == productId) {
      return key;
    }
  }
};



var List = Vue.extend({
  template: '#product-list',
  data: function () {
    return {products: products, searchKey: ''};
  },
  computed: {
    filteredProducts: function () {
      return this.products.filter(function (product) {
        return this.searchKey=='' || product.name.indexOf(this.searchKey) !== -1;
      },this);
    }
  }
});

var Product = Vue.extend({
  template: '#product',
  data: function () {
    return {product: findProduct(this.$route.params.product_id)};
  }
});

var ProductEdit = Vue.extend({
  template: '#product-edit',
  data: function () {
    return {product: findProduct(this.$route.params.product_id)};
  },
  methods: {
    updateProduct: function () {
      var product = this.product;
      products[findProductKey(product.id)] = {
        id: product.id,
        name: product.name,
        description: product.description,
        price: product.price
      };
      router.push('/');
    }
  }
});

var ProductDelete = Vue.extend({
  template: '#product-delete',
  data: function () {
    return {product: findProduct(this.$route.params.product_id)};
  },
  methods: {
    deleteProduct: function () {
      products.splice(findProductKey(this.$route.params.product_id), 1);
      router.push('/');
    }
  }
});

var AddProduct = Vue.extend({
  template: '#add-product',
  data: function () {
    return {product: {name: '', description: '', price: ''}}
  },
  methods: {
    createProduct: function() {
      var product = this.product;
      products.push({
        id: Math.random().toString().split('.')[1],
        name: product.name,
        description: product.description,
        price: product.price
      });
      router.push('/');
    }
  }
});

var router = new VueRouter({routes:[
  { path: '/', component: List},
  { path: '/product/:product_id', component: Product, name: 'product'},
  { path: '/add-product', component: AddProduct},
  { path: '/product/:product_id/edit', component: ProductEdit, name: 'product-edit'},
  { path: '/product/:product_id/delete', component: ProductDelete, name: 'product-delete'}
]});
app = new Vue({
  router:router
}).$mount('#app')</script>
```

Working code sample:

```
     <div class="container">
      <header class="page-header">
        <div class="branding">
          <img src="https://vuejs.org/images/logo.png" alt="Logo" title="Home page" class="logo"/>
          <h1>Vue.js 2 CRUD application</h1>
          <p>Ported from: <a href="http://codepen.io/-a/pen/amOYGp">Vue.js CRUD application</a></p>
        </div>
      </header>
      <main id="app">
        <router-view></router-view>
      </main>
    </div>

    <template id="product-list">
      <div>
        <div class="actions">
          <router-link class="btn btn-default" v-bind:to="{path: '/add-product'}">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>
            Add product
          </router-link>
        </div>
        <div class="filters row">
          <div class="form-group col-sm-3">
            <label for="search-element">Product name</label>
            <input v-model="searchKey" class="form-control" id="search-element" requred/>
          </div>
        </div>
        <table class="table">
          <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Description</th>
            <th>Price</th>
            <th class="col-sm-2">Actions</th>
          </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
          <tr v-for="product in filteredProducts">
            <td>
              <router-link v-bind:to="{name: 'product', params: {product_id: product.id}}">{{ product.name }}</router-link>
            </td>
            <td>{{ product.description }}</td>
            <td>
              {{ product.price }}
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-euro" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            </td>
            <td>
              <router-link class="btn btn-warning btn-xs" v-bind:to="{name: 'product-edit', params: {product_id: product.id}}">Edit</router-link>
              <router-link class="btn btn-danger btn-xs" v-bind:to="{name: 'product-delete', params: {product_id: product.id}}">Delete</router-link>
            </td>
          </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </template>

    <template id="add-product">
      <div>
        <h2>Add new product</h2>
        <form v-on:submit="createProduct">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="add-name">Name</label>
            <input class="form-control" id="add-name" v-model="product.name" required/>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="add-description">Description</label>
            <textarea class="form-control" id="add-description" rows="10" v-model="product.description"></textarea>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="add-price">Price, <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-euro"></span></label>
            <input type="number" class="form-control" id="add-price" v-model="product.price"/>
          </div>
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Create</button>
          <router-link class="btn btn-default" v-bind:to="'/'">Cancel</router-link>
        </form>
      </div>
    </template>

    <template id="product">
      <div>
        <h2>{{ product.name }}</h2>
        <b>Description: </b>
        <div>{{ product.description }}</div>
        <b>Price:</b>
        <div>{{ product.price }}<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-euro"></span></div>
        <br/>
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <router-link v-bind:to="'/'">Back to product list</router-link>
      </div>
    </template>

    <template id="product-edit">
      <div>
        <h2>Edit product</h2>
        <form v-on:submit="updateProduct">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="edit-name">Name</label>
            <input class="form-control" id="edit-name" v-model="product.name" required/>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="edit-description">Description</label>
            <textarea class="form-control" id="edit-description" rows="3" v-model="product.description"></textarea>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="edit-price">Price, <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-euro"></span></label>
            <input type="number" class="form-control" id="edit-price" v-model="product.price"/>
          </div>
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
          <router-link class="btn btn-default" v-bind:to="'/'">Cancel</router-link>
        </form>
      </div>
    </template>

    <template id="product-delete">
      <div>
        <h2>Delete product {{ product.name }}</h2>
        <form v-on:submit="deleteProduct">
          <p>The action cannot be undone.</p>
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button>
          <router-link class="btn btn-default" v-bind:to="'/'">Cancel</router-link>
        </form>
      </div>
    </template>
    <script>var vm = new Vue({
  el: '#demo',
  data: {
    sections: [
      {
          id: 1,
          city: 'Dallas',
          state: 'TX',
          zip: 75201,
          price: 162500
      }, {
          id: 2,
          city: 'Bevery Hills',
          state: 'CA',
          zip: 90210,
          price: 319250
      }, {
          id: 3,
          city: 'New York',
          state: 'NY',
          zip: 00010,
          price: 962500
      }
        ],
    columns: {
      city : {
        displayname : "City",
        sortorder : 1
      },
      zip : {
        displayname : "Zip",
        sortorder : 1
      },
      price : {
        displayname : "Price ($)",
        sortorder : 1
      }
    },
    query: '',
    sortkey: 'city',
    sortOrders: {
        city: 1,
        zip: 1,
        price: -1
      }
   },
  computed: {
    tableFilter: function () {
        return this.orderBy(this.findBy(this.sections, this.query, 'city'),this.sortOrders[this.sortkey], this.sortkey)
    }
  },
  methods: {
    findBy: function (list, value, column) {
      return list.filter(function (item) {
        return item[column].includes(value)
      })
    },
    orderBy: function (list, order, column) {
      return list.sort(function (a, b) {
        return order * (a[column] - b[column])
      })
    },
    sort: function (colKey) {
        this.sortkey = colKey
      this.sortOrders[colKey] = this.sortOrders[colKey] * -1
    }
  }
})<script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add a `v-on:click` attribute to your `<th>`:

```
<th v-on:click="sortByColumn('name')">Name</th>
```

Then add a method that sets a variable for the column and update your computed property to use it:

```
data: function() {
  return { products: products, searchKey: '', sortBy: '' };
},
computed: {
  filteredProducts: function () {
    return this.products.filter((product) => {
      ...
    }).sort((a, b) => { return (a[this.sortBy] < b[this.sortBy]) ? -1 : 1; });
  }
},
methods: {
  sortByColumn: function(columnName) {
    this.sortBy = columnName;
  }
}
```

I updated your code example here, and also added in toggling between ascending and descending order. https://codepen.io/anon/pen/vxYMLE